# Document Filter vs. KeyListener vs. MaskFormatter

Tags: java, keylistener, documentfilter

Before you jump all over me, please remember that each of you started out at some point (only saying that because I have seen the responses).  Yes, I am learning, but need some help with the differences between DocumentFilter, KeyListener, or any other way to only allow certain data.  This is for a class, but I can turn it in as it is and receive full credit.  I want to restrict the answer choices to only be A or B (case-insensitive).  I have read many articles and get more confused with each one that I read.  Please help me understand.

Code below:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;

public class HorticultureQuiz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a randomizer Object
        Random rand = new Random();
        // Object used to read the input
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        // String Array used to maintain the questions
        String[][] questions = new String[10][2];

        //Questions - 0 throuugh 9 equals 10 questions
        questions[0][0] = "Question1 \nA: True\nB: False";
        questions[1][0] = "Question2 \nA: True\nB: False";
        questions[2][0] = "Question3 \nA: True\nB: False";
        questions[3][0] = "Question4 \nA: True\nB: False";
        questions[4][0] = "Question5 \nA: True\nB: False";
        questions[4][0] = "Question5 \nA: True\nB: False";
        questions[5][0] = "Question6 \nA: True\nB: False";
        questions[6][0] = "Question7 \nA: True\nB: False";
        questions[7][0] = "Question8 \nA: True\nB: False";
        questions[8][0] = "Question9\nA: True\nB: False";
        questions[9][0] = "Question10 \nA: True\nB: False";

        //Answers
        questions[0][1] = "B";
        questions[1][1] = "B";
        questions[2][1] = "B";
        questions[3][1] = "B";
        questions[4][1] = "B";
        questions[5][1] = "B";
        questions[6][1] = "B";
        questions[7][1] = "B";
        questions[8][1] = "B";
        questions[9][1] = "B";


        int intOption;
        String strAnswer = null;

        // Used to maintain the count in the loop
        int ii = 0;

        while (ii < 5){

        // Assign the input answer a value until you reach 5
        intOption = rand.nextInt(5);
        // Print the question to the screen
        System.out.println(questions[intOption][0]);
        //Error handling
        try {
            strAnswer = input.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // If the input answer equals the correct answer in the array list
        if (strAnswer.equals(questions[intOption][1])){

            // you are correct
            System.out.println("Correct!");

            }

            else{

            // Otherwise...WRONG
            System.out.println("WRONG, the answer was " + questions[intOption][1]);

            }

        //Increment by one until you reach 5
        ii = ii + 1;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: One way you could do this is check if the input is `a`, `b`, `A` or `B` in the same way you check if they got the right answer (with `String.equals`), and if it's not you could print a message and ask for another input. Just repeat that process. It can be done all with functions you used to write this code.

Comment: Your code doesn't make use of document filters, key listeners, or mask formatters. You will get more responses if your code shows how you've tried to use these approaches. To me, there's only a very tenuous connection between your question title and your code.

Comment: Again, I don't understand it enough to even use it.  Beginner here.  I don't know how to use it...that is why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add validation to the part where you take input from the user -

```
        System.out.println(questions[intOption][0]);
        // Error handling
        try {
            do {
                strAnswer = input.readLine().toUpperCase();
            } while (!isValid(strAnswer));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Create a method `isValid` which will check if the input is a valid input or not, as shown below :

```
private static boolean isValid(String strAnswer) {
    boolean valid = strAnswer.equals("A") || strAnswer.equals("B");
    if(!valid){
        System.out.println("\nInput is not valid, please enter a valid choice - A or B");
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: This actually worked very well, but I do have a question.  If it is this simple, then why do I see so much around the topics I asked about in the subject line?  For what it is worth, I saw these covered when I was creating a form using a JFormattedTextField with a MaskFormatter and NumberFormatter.  It would seem to me that if there are a 100 ways to do something, one of them would be the preferred for specific use cases.

Comment: Simon's comment to your question answers what you mentioned in this comment. As for the simple solution I provided, it is because you wrote "please remember that each of you started out at some point". As you progress in Java, you will learn it's not about using a Class for the sake of complexity, it is about the context.

Comment: You are very correct.  Thank you so much for taking the time, and keeping it at a level that I can understand.